# I am building an fastapi application error "Unable to determine database type from python tuple type"

Tags: python, sql-server

I am using pycharm and sqlalchemy to connect to the database
The error shown is as follows
"Unable to determine database type from python tuple type"

db.py file

```
import sqlalchemy


user_name = ''
password = ''
server = ''
db_name = 
DATABASE_URL = f"mssql+pymssql://{user_name}:{password}@{server}/{db_name}"
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(DATABASE_URL)




rom .route import account
from ...shared.db import engine


@account.post("/login")
async def login(email: str, password: str):
    try:
        mode: str = "LOGIN",
        userid: int = 0,
        loginip: str = " ",
        loginbrowser: str = ""
        connection = engine.raw_connection()
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.callproc('SP_Login', (mode, email, password, loginip, loginbrowser, userid))
        # result = []
        for row in cursor:
            print(row)
            break
        return row
        connection.commit()
        # print(result)
```

```
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: Mysql<>ms sql server! You are using the latter, not the former...